# OPPO R2001 YOYO usb driver not found for debugging apps from Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, adb

I have an Android Mobile OPPO R2001 YOYO. I want to debug apps on this device from Android Studio. I'm using Windows 8.1 but I can't find the USB driver for this device. I tried the OPPO ADB driver that's recommended by this link but it's not working:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers.

I searched for drivers for this device from different websites but it's still not working and it's showing the following message when I update the driver software from device manager:

> Windows was unable to install your R2001 Android Phone

Can anybody help me to solve this situation?

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the Google USB Driver
2. Unzip the package
3. Open the file `android_winusb.inf`, which is located in that package
4. Find the Hadware Id of your device:

   4.1. Go to the Device Manager

   4.2. Right-Click on your device

   4.3  Select Properties

   4.4  Go to Details

   4.5  Select Hardware Ids
5. Make a new entry in your `android_winusb.inf` file

   This could look like this:

   ```
         [Google.NTx86]
         ;GT90H //this would be your device name so sth like r2001
         %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1F3A&PID_1009&MI_01 //this is the short one of your hardware ids
         %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1F3A&PID_1009&REV_0233&MI_01 //this is the long one of your hardware ids
         %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1F3A&PID_1009&MI_01 //this is the short one of your hardware ids
         %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1F3A&PID_1009&REV_0233&MI_01 //this is the long one of your hardware ids
   ```

   So you just need to give the device another name and replace the `USB\VID_1F3A&PID_1009&MI_01` and `USB\VID_1F3A&PID_1009&REV_0233&MI_01` with your Hardware Device Ids and save it.
6. Then choose at the driver-installation that windows should search through your unziped folder for a driver.
7. As I heard on Windows 8.1 you must choose ‘Disable driver signature enforcement‘ in your Device-Manager before you can install the driver. But I can't test this, because I´m running on Windows 7